# C# guessing game with only X tries

Tags: c#

This is basically my first little  C# program. I built in a "rule" so you only have 20 tries to guess the correct number. I was wondering if there is a more beautiful way to implement this "rule".

This is my code:

```
        bool run = true;


        while (run == true) // Main While Schleife
        {

            Random rndnr = new Random();
            int rnd;
            rnd = rndnr.Next(1, 100);
            int guess;
            int trys;
            trys = 0;
            guess = 0;



            Console.WriteLine("Can you guess my number? I am thinking about a number between 1 and 100!");
            guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(rnd);

            while (guess != rnd)
            {


                if (trys > 20)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You only have 20 trys. You failed! \n");
                    run = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you wann play again? Press R + Enter to play again!");
                    string rerun = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    if (rerun == "R")
                    {
                        run = true;
                        trys = 0;
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        run = false;
                        break;

                    }


                }





            if (guess > rnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("My number is lower than" + guess + "\n guess again >>");
                guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            if (guess < rnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("My number is higher than" + guess + "\n guess again >>");
                guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            if (guess == rnd)
            {

                Console.Write("You guessed right my number is" + rnd + "and you needed " + trys + "trys");
                run = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Do you wann play again? Press R + Enter to play again!");
                string rerun = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                if (rerun == "R")
                {
                    run = true;
                    trys = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                }

                else
                {
                    run = false;
                    break;
                }
            }


            trys++;
            }




        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for palying see you next time!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have working code and you just want to know how to improve it, you should post to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: 20 guesses is way too many for a number between 1 and 100. you should not allow more than `1 + (log(100) / log(2))` since you are dividing the space of possible numbers by 2 with every guess .. just a sidenote

Comment: If you are calling `rndnr.Next(1, 100)` then you are getting number between 1 and 99, not 1 and 100. Also, don't instantiate `Random` more than once per thread - it can lead to repeated numbers in tight loops - so it's a good habit to get in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few bug fixes and generally tried to improve the code a bit. Hope you find it helpful:

```
    bool run = true;
    int maxTrys=20;
    Random random = new Random();

    while (run)
    {
        int rnd=random.Next(1, 101);

        Console.WriteLine("Can you guess my number? I am thinking about a number between 1 and 100!");
        int trys=0;
        bool solved=false;
        while (!solved && trys<maxTrys)
        {
            trys++;
            int guess;
            bool numericGuess;
            do {
                numericGuess=int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out guess);
                if (!numericGuess) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                }
            } while (!numericGuess);

            if (guess > rnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("My number is lower than {0}\n guess again >>", guess));
            }
            else if (guess < rnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("My number is higher than {0}\n guess again >>", guess));
            }
            else if (guess == rnd)
            {
                solved=true;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("You guessed right my number is {0} and you needed {1} trys", rnd, trys));
            }
        }
        if (!solved) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("You only have {0} trys. You failed! \n", maxTrys));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Do you wanna play again? Press R + Enter to play again!");
        string rerun = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        if (!rerun.Equals("R"))
        {
            run = false;
        }
    }
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing see you next time!");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 Random r = new Random();

            int secretNumber = r.Next(1, 11);
            int i = 0;
            int chance = 5;

            Console.WriteLine("Game: guess number");

            while (i < chance)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your turn");

                if (secretNumber == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                    break;
                }

                i++;
            }

            if (i == chance)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You lost!");
                Console.WriteLine("The secret number is " + secretNumber);
            }
```

Simple way